# Trouble with Ball bat collision in SDL2 breakout game C++

Tags: c++, sdl, game-physics, sdl-2, game-development

Hello I'm making a simple break out game using SDL 2 for Switch using C++ and Homebrew sdk. I was able to implement Ball colliding with screen boundaries.But I'm unable to do ball bat collision. Here is my code.You can ignore some switch initialisation code.

My idea was if ball.x == bat.x and ball.y == bat.y then make ball_vel_y = -ball_vel_y

But my idea didn't work out. Is there is any other way to do it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>
#include<switch.h>
// some switch buttons
#define JOY_A     0
#define JOY_B     1
#define JOY_X     2
#define JOY_Y     3
#define JOY_PLUS  10
#define JOY_MINUS 11
#define JOY_LEFT  12
#define JOY_UP    13
#define JOY_RIGHT 14
#define JOY_DOWN  15
#define KEY_LSTICK_UP 17
#define KEY_LSTICK_DOWN 19
#define KEY_LSTICK_LEFT 16
#define KEY_LSTICK_RIGHT 18

bool Quit = false;
SDL_Event event;
int ball_x = 20;
int ball_y = 50;
int ball_vel_x = 1;
int ball_vel_y = 1;

int bkw = 1920;
int bkh = 1080;
int bkwmin = 0;
int bkhmin = 0;

int bat_x = bkw /2 ;
int bat_y = bkh - 300;;





void BallCollision()
{
    if(ball_x <= bkwmin || ball_x >= bkw - 60)
    {
        ball_vel_x = -ball_vel_x;
    }
    if(ball_y <= bkhmin || ball_y >= bkh - 300)
    {
        ball_vel_y = -ball_vel_y;
    }

    //ball bat collision here
   
  
}




void MoveBall()
{
    ball_x += ball_vel_x * 5;
    ball_y += ball_vel_y * 5;
}
void EventHandler()
{
     if(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
  
       
                         Quit = true;
        
             }

            else if(event.type == SDL_JOYBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                 if(event.jbutton.button == KEY_LSTICK_LEFT && bat_x > 0)
                 {
                    bat_x -= 2*50;
                 }
                 else if(event.jbutton.button == KEY_LSTICK_RIGHT && bat_x < bkw - 100)
                 {
                     bat_x += 2*50;
                 }
            }
    }
}
int main()
{

     SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK);
     SDL_Window* Window = SDL_CreateWindow("HelloWorld",0,0,1920, 1080,SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
     SDL_Renderer* Renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(Window,0,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED|SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
     
     romfsInit();
     
    
    

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (SDL_JoystickOpen(i) == NULL) {
            SDL_Log("SDL_JoystickOpen: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            SDL_Quit();
            return -1;
        }
    }

   
    SDL_Rect bkrect;
    bkrect.x = 0;
    bkrect.y = 0;
    bkrect.h = 1080;
    bkrect.w = 1920;

    
   
    SDL_Surface* ball = SDL_LoadBMP("romfs:/resources/ball.bmp");
    SDL_Texture* balltexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Renderer,ball);

    SDL_Surface* BackgroundImage = SDL_LoadBMP("romfs:/resources/bk.bmp");
    SDL_Texture* BackgroundTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Renderer,BackgroundImage); 

    SDL_Surface* bat = SDL_LoadBMP("romfs:/resources/bat.bmp");
    SDL_Texture* battexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Renderer,bat);

    
    
    

    while(!Quit)
    {
          
    
    EventHandler();
     MoveBall();
     BallCollision();

    
    SDL_Rect ballrect;
    ballrect.x = ball_x;
    ballrect.y = ball_y;
    ballrect.h = 60;
    ballrect.w = 60;

    SDL_Rect batrect;
    batrect.x = bat_x;
    batrect.y = bat_y;
    batrect.w = 100;
    batrect.h = 50;
    
    SDL_RenderCopy(Renderer,BackgroundTexture,NULL,&bkrect);
    SDL_RenderCopy(Renderer,balltexture,NULL,&ballrect);
    SDL_RenderCopy(Renderer,battexture,NULL,&batrect);
    
    SDL_RenderPresent(Renderer);
    SDL_RenderClear(Renderer);
   
  

    
    }
    

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(Renderer);
    romfsExit();
    SDL_DestroyWindow(Window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to check whether your ball's path from current to new position intersects with the rectangle formed by the paddle. Your proposed solution reduces the paddle to a single point, which is _very_ hard to do aim ;)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply I have solved it by creating a simple collision checking system

Comment: Something you can look up for this would be "swept sphere AABB collision".  A solution would be to translate everything into "ball" space. This removes the radius from the equation and will simplify things. You can then do a line-line intersection test. The ball's current and target position would create one line segment, the paddle from end to end is the other. The intersection would be in time along the ball's line and give the exact intersection point on the paddle (if value is between 0 and 1). Use this time index to position the ball so it appears to hit the paddle and not overlap it.